# how to read serial data at a particular offset of u8 array

Tags: rust

How to read serial data at a particular offset of an `u8` array? Also how to pass the number of bytes that needs to be read from the port as an argument to `read` method?

```
use serial2::{SerialPort, Settings};

pub struct SerialInterface {
    port: Option<SerialPort>,
    dev_name: String,
}

impl SerialInterface {
    pub fn new(dev_name: &str, baud_rate: u32) -> SerialInterface {
        SerialInterface {
            port: SerialPort::open(dev_name, |mut curr_settings: Settings| {
                let _ = curr_settings.set_baud_rate(baud_rate);
                Result::Ok(curr_settings)
            }).ok(),
            dev_name: dev_name.to_string(),
        }
    }

    // reads exactly read_len bytes
    pub fn receive_data(&self, mut buff: &mut[u8], mut read_len: usize) {
        let mut recvd_len = 0;
        while read_len > recvd_len {
            // read 1 byte data at a time
            // the below line isn't correct. I'm trying to imitate `C` serial `read` call
            // recvd_len += self.port.as_ref().unwrap().read(&mut buff[recvd_len..], 1);
        }

    }
}

fn main() {
    let ser_intf = SerialInterface::new("/dev/ttyUSB1", 115200 as u32);
    let mut buff: [u8; 256] = [0; 256];
    ser_intf.receive_data(&mut buff, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`read_exact`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_exact) and pass it a slice with the expected length and offset:

```
pub fn receive_data(&mut self, buff: &mut[u8], offset: usize, read_len: usize) {
    self.port.as_mut().unwrap().read_exact (&mut buff[offset .. offset + read_len]).unwrap()
}
```

Comment: `read_exact` requires `&mut self`